# Selfhost servicestack, have to restart to serve a new static file

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have a servicestack server that sometimes has to serve a static .cab file for download.
If the file is in the server directory, I run the server, test with a browser 127.0.0.1:3105/607.cab and works.
But if the server is already running, I copy the 607.cab in the directory, and receive a 404 not found.
Then I close and restart the server, and it downloads...
Any hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The files in the top-level directory is cached to avoid File System hits to determine if the request is for a static file or not.

Put the content in a subfolder (which is not cached).

Comment: sorry, just tried, using a updates/ directory in the root and going for 172.0.0.1:3105/updates/610.cab and received 404
Restarted the server, pressed refresh in the browser, and had 610.cab served.
Am I doing something wrong?